# I want to put my jar file in html code

Tags: java, html, jar

How can I put my jar file into my html?

I tried to use that:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet code=Tictactoe.class archive="Test.jar">
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when Im trying to run my html code java is blocking my jar file.

Comment: maybe a permissions problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your url (local or distant server url) in exception list on java settings panel.

[image]

Comment: @user3819756 You should verify that java plugin is installed and activated on your browser, and use web server like Apache HTTP server for testing, and add the address of your web server to the exceptions list on java settings panel.

Comment: @user3819756 For security issues, Oracle has stopped to run local jars, so to test your jar (applet) inside html file you should install web server (like [Apache HTTP](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi)) and put your html file with your jar inside "Apache_Install_Location/htdocs" folder then start your server and launch your browser with http://localhost/ url.